# value index lengh

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
      Col1
0      A
1      B
3      D
4      A
5      A
```

I would like to create a column that calculates the difference of index between 2 occurences of same value. I would get:

```
      Col1      Col2
0      A         0
1      B         0
3      D         0
4      A         4
5      A         1
```

for each value I would like to do that, in this example B and D occured once.

Any suggestions ? thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you convert the index to a Series, you can use a groupby-diff exactly as you usually would:

```
In [102]: df
Out[102]: 
  Col1
0    A
1    B
3    D
4    A
5    A
6    D

In [103]: df["Col2"] = df.index.to_series().groupby(df.Col1).diff().fillna(0)

In [104]: df
Out[104]: 
  Col1  Col2
0    A   0.0
1    B   0.0
3    D   0.0
4    A   4.0
5    A   1.0
6    D   3.0
```